# Django - template does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I imported this library to my django project: https://github.com/percipient/django-allauth-2fa/blob/master/allauth_2fa/views.py.

I keep getting this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /setup/
base.html
In template C:\Users\Davide\lib\site-packages\allauth_2fa\templates\allauth_2fa\setup.html, error at line 1

1   {% extends 'base.html' %}
```

I don't know why it's showing that error, because i created my own **setup.html** at **project/templates** and it looks like this instead:

```
**{% extends 'main/header.html' %}**
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

//
```

My **urls.py** looks like this:

```
from allauth_2fa import views as allauth_2fa_views
app_name = "project"

urlpatterns = [

    path("setup/", allauth_2fa_views.TwoFactorSetup.as_view(), name="setup"),
    // Other urls
```

Answer (score 0):

In your base.html write:

```
{% include 'main/header.html' %}
```

and don't forget to write at the top in the template (setup.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't know where that base.html comes from. I only have a setup.html but not a base.html

Comment: Check the first line of your setup.html, it seems like that's the line of code you have :  {% extends 'base.html' %}

Comment: I will still get the error, the problem is that my setup.html and the file where the error is, are two different files

Comment: Maybe you need to give us more information, like what folder or directory did you create in your templates folder. Are you using the setup.html as a Master Page or base.html ? Where have you saved the header.html ? ..... etc.  Only if you give me a little more information i will be able to help you.  Thank you !